# Programmatically pair bluetooth device as audio device

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bluetooth

I'm developing a business application with windows 10, that should automatically connect to a given bluetooth speaker/headset (Jabra FREEWAY v5.7.0).
Using the BluetoothAPIs.h this works well so far. Problem is, it does not show up as audio device under windows. I can't play a test sound (or any other) on it.
How do I pair the device as audio device? or are there any subsequent steps to set the device as audio?

We have similar code functioning for a mobile printer, there seems no need to do extra steps there.
Connecting the device (Jabra) with the given windows opporunities shows it correctly as audio device.

```
BOOL CALLBACK BTHeadsetAuthCallbackEx(__in_opt LPVOID /*pvParam*/, __in PBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_PARAMS pAuthCallbackParams)
{
  BLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATE_RESPONSE resp;
  resp.bthAddressRemote = pAuthCallbackParams->deviceInfo.Address;
  resp.authMethod = pAuthCallbackParams->authenticationMethod;
  resp.negativeResponse = FALSE;
  resp.passkeyInfo.passkey = pAuthCallbackParams->Passkey;
  DWORD ret = BluetoothSendAuthenticationResponseEx( NULL, &resp );
  if( ret != ERROR_SUCCESS )
  {
    logError( "BluetoothSendAuthenticationResponseEx failed with %u", ret );
    return FALSE;
  }

  return TRUE;
}


BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO deviceInfo = { sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO) };
deviceInfo.Address.ullLong = device->getAddress();

HBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_REGISTRATION regHandle;
DWORD err = BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx( &deviceInfo, &regHandle, (PFN_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_EX)&BTHeadsetAuthCallbackEx, NULL );
if( err != ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
  logError( "BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx failed with %u", err );
  return false;
}

err = BluetoothAuthenticateDevice( NULL, NULL, &deviceInfo, L"0000", 4 );
if( err != ERROR_SUCCESS  )
{
  BluetoothUnregisterAuthentication( regHandle );
  logError( "BluetoothAuthenticateDevice failed with %u", err );
  return false;
}

BluetoothUnregisterAuthentication( regHandle );
```

Comment: [BluetoothSetServiceState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothsetservicestate) is what you need to use to install service for your device.

Comment: thanks, I'll try with BluetoothSetServiceState. Problem is, it needs a UUID of the device, which I might not have.

Comment: It requires UUID of service, not device. Your device supports one of the following profile (server): HandsFree, A2DP. You can check which service is supported by Bluetooth Profile Scanner android app.

Comment: after an extensive web search my colleague pointed me here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-bluetooth, where I got the GUID for Handfree devices:0000111E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB which worked smoothly. I'll write an answer with complete code, if anyone comes accros the same problem.

Comment: There is no need to search cause first link in Google by "Bluetooth UUIDs" gives the correct answer: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery

Comment: There are something known as short UUID. To get long UUID yo uhave to get BASE_UUID (00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB) and change first word to short UUID. For SPP (0x1101) it is 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out by Mike Petrichenko I needed to call BluetoothSetServiceState() with a correct service GUID (hands-free devices in my case), which I found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-bluetooth

Complete code:

```
BOOL CALLBACK BTHeadsetAuthCallbackEx(__in_opt LPVOID /*pvParam*/, __in PBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_PARAMS pAuthCallbackParams)
{
  BLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATE_RESPONSE resp;
  resp.bthAddressRemote = pAuthCallbackParams->deviceInfo.Address;
  resp.authMethod = pAuthCallbackParams->authenticationMethod;
  resp.negativeResponse = FALSE;
  resp.passkeyInfo.passkey = pAuthCallbackParams->Passkey;
  DWORD ret = BluetoothSendAuthenticationResponseEx( NULL, &resp );
  if( ret != ERROR_SUCCESS )
  {
    logError( "BluetoothSendAuthenticationResponseEx failed with %u", ret );
    return FALSE;
  }

  return TRUE;
}

BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO deviceInfo = { sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO) };
deviceInfo.Address.ullLong = device->getAddress();

HBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_REGISTRATION regHandle;
DWORD err = BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx( &deviceInfo, &regHandle, (PFN_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_EX)&BTHeadsetAuthCallbackEx, NULL );
if( err != ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
  logError( "BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx failed with %u", err );
  return false;
}

err = BluetoothAuthenticateDevice( NULL, NULL, &deviceInfo, L"0000", 4 );
if( err != ERROR_SUCCESS  )
{
  BluetoothUnregisterAuthentication( regHandle );
  logError( "BluetoothAuthenticateDevice failed with %u", err );
  return false;
}

BluetoothUnregisterAuthentication( regHandle );

HANDLE btHeadset;
BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS rfind = { sizeof( rfind ) };
BluetoothFindFirstRadio( &rfind, &btHeadset );
GUID id = { 0x0000111e, 0x0000, 0x1000, { 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x5f, 0x9b, 0x34, 0xfb} }; 
err = BluetoothSetServiceState( &btHeadset, &deviceInfo, &id, BLUETOOTH_SERVICE_ENABLE );
if( err != ERROR_SUCCESS  )
{
  logError( "BluetoothSetServiceState failed with %u", err );
}

logNorm( "BluetoothSetServiceState successfull" );
```

note: this is not completely fool proof. I'm using the first device found with empty search parameters. Some refining will be implemented there.